# Sendgrid not sending mail on server

Tags: laravel, sendgrid

I am using Sendgrid for first time and I am integrating it with my Laravel 7 project. I signed up on sendgrid and generated the API KEY and successfully configured the `.env` file.

Now I am able to send and receive mail on localhost but when I am using same configuration on server it is giving me following error

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`ip-107-180-95-117.ip.secureserver.net' did not match expected CN=`smtp.sendgrid.net
```

I tried to google the solution and came across these two solutions

**1) replacing the tls with empty string:** I removed `tls` from `.env` file and replaced `tls` with empty string in `mail.php` file

**2) added the following code in mail.php**

```
'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
            'stream' => [
                'ssl' => [
                    'allow_self_signed' => true,
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

both of these solutions leads me to another error which is following

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "apikey" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication data
↵". Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication data
```

What is possibly wrong with my Godaddy server because sendgrid is working on localhost

Comment: The server you're connecting to is presenting a certificate for ip-107-180-95-117.ip.secureserver.net, but you are trying to connect to smtp.sendgrid.net. I would confirm you have your server settings correct, confirm your traffic is not being proxied or intercepted, and then contact your mail provider for help.

Comment: DO NOT set verify_peer to false, unless you want to have your messages intercepted, altered, and destroyed.